# making to do application with JS but EventListener is not working after i press submit (still new to JS)

Tags: javascript, html, web, addeventlistener

## I am trying to make To-do application with JS everything works fine but i can't delete after pressing submit and i don't understand why , if anyone can help me would be greatful

Here is a Code in
[code](https://codepen.io/Minasamir785/pen/zYaVEmQ?fbclid=IwAR3OQtDECaYv1GC7Q6E-BE1NuhQC_r0_MCNkYubP64HvIVL_Tt6Z5qax5N8)

`your text`

I Have checked the code but couldn't figure it out So please Help!

Comment: See [Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254428/4642212) — in short: no. Please [edit] your question and provide a [mre] (this means, your _code must be in the question itself, as [formatted text](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/251361/4642212)_), along with your _desired_ results, your _actual_ results, including all _errors_, and demonstrate _your research and your attempts_ and explain what precisely didn’t work. Use the [browser console (dev tools)](//webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/8525) (hit `F12`), read any errors.

Comment: while a code pen is fine, try to post the code it self. Check browser `console` for possible errors, `console.log` to track progress of calling the function, or use a debugger

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well this might fix the code.

This is mostly the code posted in the pen.

```
let task = document.getElementsByClassName("taskName")[0];
let sub =  document.querySelector("#sub");
let ls = document.getElementsByClassName("ls")[0];
let dels = document.querySelectorAll(".submmit");
let tasks = [];

if (window.localStorage.task){

  tasks = JSON.parse(window.localStorage.task);

  ls.innerHTML = ``;
  for(let i = 0 ; i < tasks.length ; i++){
    let ele = document.createElement("div");
    let del = document.createElement("div");
    del.innerHTML = `Delete`;
    del.className = `submmit`
    ele.innerHTML = tasks[i];
    ele.className = 'task';
    ls.appendChild(ele)
    ls.appendChild(del)
    del.addEventListener("click",delEle); 
  }

}




sub.addEventListener("click",store) ; 

function store(){
  tasks.push(task.value)
  window.localStorage.setItem("task",JSON.stringify(tasks))
  let currTasks = JSON.parse(window.localStorage.task);

  ls.innerHTML = ``;

  for(let i = 0 ; i < currTasks.length ; i++){
    let ele = document.createElement("div");
    let del = document.createElement("div");
    del.innerHTML = `Delete`;
    del.className = `submmit`
    ele.innerHTML = currTasks[i];
    ele.className = 'task';
    ls.appendChild(ele)
    ls.appendChild(del)
    del.addEventListener("click",delEle); 
  }

}



function delEle(e){
  for(let i = 0 ; i < tasks.length ; i++){
    if(e.currentTarget.previousElementSibling.innerHTML === tasks[i]){
      
      tasks.splice(i, 1); 
      console.log(tasks)
      break;
    }
  }
  ls.removeChild(e.currentTarget.previousElementSibling)
  ls.removeChild(e.currentTarget)
  window.localStorage.setItem("task",JSON.stringify(tasks))
  
}
```

One simple thing you can do to improve the code is, you can remove the duplications.

Create a function to create `To-Do`s.

Comment: Thanks for Your replay it worked , Maybe the problem really was duplications, Thanks again